How to update database of parent class and [Owned] attribute class type in Entity Framework Core 8.0.8
How to save the [Owned] attribute class data from parent class into the database.
This is the parent class:
[Index(nameof(EmailId),IsUnique =true)]
public class User : Entity, IUser
{
   [Required(ErrorMessage ="First Name is required."), MaxLength(20),MinLength(1)]
   [DisplayName("First Name")]
   public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

   [DisplayName("Last Name")]
   [Required(ErrorMessage ="Last Name is required."), MaxLength(20),MinLength(1)]
   public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

   [DisplayName("Email Address")]
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Id is required"), MaxLength(50), MinLength(5)]
   [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
   public string EmailId { get; set; } = string.Empty;

   [JsonIgnore]
   [DisplayName("Password"),MaxLength(200), MinLength(8),DataType(DataType.Password)]
   public string? Password { get; set; }    

   [JsonIgnore]
   public List<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
}

And this is the child class RefreshToken structure
[Owned]
public class RefreshToken
{
   [Key]
   [JsonIgnore]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }= Guid.NewGuid();
   public string Token { get; set; }
   public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
   public DateTime Created { get; set; }
   public string CreatedByIp { get; set; }
   public DateTime? Revoked { get; set; }
   public string RevokedByIp { get;set; }
   public string ReplacedByToken { get; set; }
   public string ReasonRevoked { get; set; }
   public Boolean IsExpired => DateTime.UtcNow >= Expires;
   public bool IsRevoked => Revoked != null;
   public bool IsActive => !IsRevoked && !IsExpired;
}

Here is the code - I'm trying to save a parent with refresh token values:
_unitOfWork.BeginTransaction();

User? _user = GetByEmailId(model.EmailId).FirstOrDefault();

// return null if user not found
if (_user == null) 
    throw new AppException("Username or password is incorrect");

if (_user.Password != model.Password.Hash())
    throw new AppException("Username or password is incorrect");

// authentication successful so generate jwt token
var token = _jwtUtils.GenerateJwtToken(_user);
var _refreshtoken = _jwtUtils.GenerateRefreshToken(ipAddress);

_user.RefreshTokens.Add(_refreshtoken);

// remove old refresh token
removeOldRefreshTokens(_user);

apiResponse = _unitOfWork.Repository<User>().Update(_user);
_unitOfWork.SaveChange();
_unitOfWork.CommitTransaction();

While saving I'm getting an error:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: the database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s);

Refresh token is added in the collection of user table but while saving the user table I'm getting an error
enter image description here
Below is the code for removeOldRefreshToken and Update for your reference:
private void removeOldRefreshTokens(User user)
{
    // remove old inactive refresh tokens from user based on TTL in app settings
    user.RefreshTokens.RemoveAll(x =>
   !x.IsActive &&
   x.Created.AddDays(_appSettings.RefreshTokenTTL) <= DateTime.UtcNow);

}
//this code is written in generic repository
public ApiResponse Update(TEntity entity)
{        
    try
    {
        if (entity == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("entity is null"); }
        _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    
        _entity.Update(entity);
        //await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();    
    
        apiResponse.message = MessageType.Successful;
        apiResponse.status=true;
        apiResponse.userData = entity;
        return apiResponse;
 }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       apiResponse.message=MessageType.Unsuccessful;
       apiResponse.status=false;
       return apiResponse;
  }

}

The reason for that is pretty simple actually.
Generally, when EF tries to update data in table (insert or update), it looks at the Key property (in our case it's Id as usual). When it is present, EF assumes that it's need to be updated (it begins tracking it in Modified state). And so, it will send update query to DB.
In our case, you have defined:
[Key]
[JsonIgnore]
public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

Meaning, anytime you create new entity of the class, it will have Id automatically initialized.
Then, EF will see that and will try to update the entity.
In your case, you are creating new entities to INSERT to table. But since the Id is autogenerated on the code, EF will try to UPDATE the entity.
In return, EF will get that "0 rows were affected", while EF expected to UPDATE and affect 1 entity. Thus the error.
To fix that, before sending new entity to DB, you can set Id to Guid.Empty or remove Id initialization from the RefreshToken class.

Thanks, Michal, As you said I removed Guid.New() from the refresh table and it works and the error is gone.

Looks for the most part Ok, but it may depend on what removeOldRefreshTokens(_user); does, and what _unitOfWork.Repository<User>().Update(_user); does.
The first issue I do see is the client-side generation of the token's key. This is fine, but when following the convention of "Id" or "TokenId", by default EF will be expecting to treat the key as an Identity column. (generated by DB). Marking it as [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] may resolve your issue.
When it comes to this "removeOldRefreshTokens" as long as this method is iterating over the list of tokens and removing invalid items with .Remove() then this should be Ok. The warning flag I see is how the tokens are defined in the user entity:
public List<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }

Change this to:
public virtual ICollection<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; } = [];

No public setter. If any code objects to this, clean up this code. Navigation collections in entities should never be re-initialized. This will break tracking proxies leading to errors.
Lastly the Update method. Generic Repositories are an anti-pattern when it comes to EF and can likely cause you more issues than they ever could be worth. EF already provides a unit of work as the DbContext, and a repository in the DbSet. Anything over-top of this can hide annoying problems with change tracking and references. If this Update method is doing anything other than _context.SaveChanges(); then it may very well cause problems. It will almost certainly cause issues if it is calling DbSet<User>.Update(). Update() is intended for detached entities, and working with detached object graphs (relationships) is always a pain compared to tracked entities.

code for removeOldRefreshTokens and generic repository added. [Owned] type is added in refresh token collection but while saving I'm getting an DbUpdateConcurrencyException. Do you know how to update child class in database as it does not have dbset object

It should be tracking the owned entities, for something like Remove as well you should also check that your GetByEmailId is eager loading the Tokens. You may need some explicit configuration for the PK/FK within the owned token types. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#collections-of-owned-types.  If you are still having issues I'd suggest temporarily removing all unknowns with the repository and unit of work. Try it with just the DbContext and .Users. If that works then work through the repository methods.

Code like _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified; _entity.Update(entity); are certainly things that should not be needed/recommended when working with entities, especially ones with relations.
